# Getting exceptions in dialog box having endless adapter implementation for its listview

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

This is my Demo Adapter.

```
public class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {

    private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
    private View pendingView = null;
    private ArrayList<ShipTo> next;
    private static ArrayList<ShipTo> list;
    private int pageFrom = 1;
    private static Activity act;

    DemoAdapter(Context ctxt, ArrayList<ShipTo> list) {
        super(new Adapater());
            act = (Activity) ctxt;
        DemoAdapter.list = list;
        rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(600);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.row, null);

        pendingView = row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        pendingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pendingView = row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
        pendingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startProgressAnimation();

        return (row);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
        // SystemClock.sleep(1000); // pretend to do work
        pageFrom += 10;
        next = ItemController.getInstance().getShipTo(pageFrom + "", "10", "0");
        return (ItemController.moreShipTo.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendCachedData() {
                if (next != null)
            list.addAll(next);
        if (!(ItemController.moreShipTo.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) ? true : false)
            Toast.makeText(act, "No More Category found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

    }

    void startProgressAnimation() {
        if (pendingView != null) {
            pendingView.startAnimation(rotate);
        }
    }

    private static class Adapater extends BaseAdapter {

        private class ViewHolder {
            private TextView tv;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ShipTo getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            try {
                ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                ShipTo shipTo = list.get(arg0);
                LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) act
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                // if (arg1 == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                arg1 = lf.inflate(R.layout.category_spinner_textview, null);
                viewHolder.tv = (TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1_cat_spinner);

                arg1.setTag(viewHolder);
                /*
                 * } else { viewHolder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag(); }
                 */

                viewHolder.tv.setText(shipTo.getName());
                arg1.setTag(R.layout.category_spinner_textview, shipTo);
                viewHolder.tv.setPadding(5, 10, 0, 10);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return arg1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity for showing listview using endless adapter in Dialog box.

```
public class EndlessAdapterDemo extends Activity {
    public ArrayList<ShipTo> shipToList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        shipToList = ItemController.getInstance().getShipTo(
                                "1", "10", "0");

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                showCategoryList();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });

    }

    private void showCategoryList() {
        final Dialog categoryDialog = new Dialog(this);
        categoryDialog.setTitle("Select Category");
        categoryDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custumdialoglstview);
        ListView lv = (ListView) categoryDialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        DemoAdapter adapter = null;

        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new DemoAdapter(EndlessAdapterDemo.this, shipToList);
        }
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                System.out.println(arg1.getTag().getClass().getName());
                ShipTo temp = (ShipTo) arg1
                        .getTag(R.layout.category_spinner_textview);
                categoryDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        categoryDialog.show();


        }

    }
```

When I run the above code it throws illegal state exception or null pointer exception.

Following is my logcat details

```
11-17 09:40:08.532: D/AndroidRuntime(331): Shutting down VM
11-17 09:40:08.532: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1135)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1218)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-17 09:40:08.541: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Post your Logcat errors, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: At which line you are getting this error.

Comment: I don't know, I have been trying to trace that line only. If I put my getView code in try catch block I get either nullPointerException or illegalStateException. And if I remove try block I get ArrayIndexOutofBoundException on this line ShipTo shipTo = list.get(arg0); in my getView Method.

Comment: "And if I remove try block I get ArrayIndexOutofBoundException on this line ShipTo shipTo = list.get(arg0); in my getView Method" -- then fix this bug, along with all the other flaws in `Adapater`.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in getView - Is it not a known bug in endless adapters?The solution I found for this was to put the content of getView method in try catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library might be helpful to you https://github.com/yfranz/DynamicList instead of commonsware endless adapters.